# kill a function after a certain time in windows

Tags: python

I've read a lot of posts about using threads, subprocesses, etc.. A lot of it seems over complicated for what I'm trying to do...

All I want to do is stop executing a function after X amount of time has elapsed.

```
def big_loop(bob):
    x = bob
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        print time.time()-start
```

This function is an endless loop that never throws any errors or exceptions, period.
I"m not sure the difference between "commands, shells, subprocesses, threads, etc.." and this function, which is why I'm having trouble manipulating subprocesses.

I found this code here, and tried it but as you can see it keeps printing after 10 seconds have elapsed:

```
import time
import threading
import subprocess as sub
import time

class RunCmd(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd, timeout):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        self.p = sub.Popen(self.cmd)
        self.p.wait()

    def Run(self):
        self.start()
        self.join(self.timeout)

        if self.is_alive():
            self.p.terminate()
            self.join()

def big_loop(bob):
    x = bob
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        print time.time()-start

RunCmd(big_loop('jimijojo'), 10).Run()  #supposed to quit after 10 seconds, but doesn't
x = raw_input('DONEEEEEEEEEEEE')
```

What's a simple way this function can be killed. As you can see in my attempt above, it doesn't terminate after 20 seconds and just keeps on going...

***OH also, I've read about using signal, but I"m on windows so I can't use the alarm feature..  (python 2.7)

**assume the "infinitely running function" can't be manipulated or changed to be non-infinite, if I could change the function, well I'd just change it to be non infinite wouldn't I?

Here are some similar questions, which I haven't able to port over their code to work with my simple function:
Perhaps you can?

[Python: kill or terminate subprocess when timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158502/python-kill-or-terminate-subprocess-when-timeout)

[signal.alarm replacement in Windows [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644073/signal-alarm-replacement-in-windows-python)

Ok I tried an answer I received, it works.. but how can I use it if I remove the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement? When I remove this statement, the loop never ends as it did before..

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import time


def infinite_loop_function(bob):
    var = bob
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print time.time()-start
    print 'this statement will never print'

def wrapper(queue, bob):
    result = infinite_loop_function(bob)
    queue.put(result)
    queue.close()



#if __name__ == "__main__":

queue = multiprocessing.Queue(1) # Maximum size is 1
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrapper, args=(queue, 'var'))
proc.start()

# Wait for TIMEOUT seconds
try:
    timeout = 10
    result = queue.get(True, timeout)
except Queue.Empty:
    # Deal with lack of data somehow
    result = None
finally:
    proc.terminate()

print 'running other code, now that that infinite loop has been defeated!'
print 'bla bla bla'
x = raw_input('done')
```

Comment: Do you know the time `X` you want the loop to run in advance? If so, why not just check if the elapsed time is greater than `X` in the loop condition?

Comment: Yes I want X to be dynamic, in this case I'd like this infinite loop terminated after 20 seconds.

Comment: because the function I'm running can't be manipulated, just assume it is infinite and you can't edit it, obviously I need some kind of workaround to "time it out"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the building blocks in the `multiprocessing` module:

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue

TIMEOUT = 5

def big_loop(bob):
    import time
    time.sleep(4)
    return bob*2

def wrapper(queue, bob):
    result = big_loop(bob)
    queue.put(result)
    queue.close()

def run_loop_with_timeout():
    bob = 21 # Whatever sensible value you need
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(1) # Maximum size is 1
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrapper, args=(queue, bob))
    proc.start()

    # Wait for TIMEOUT seconds
    try:
        result = queue.get(True, TIMEOUT)
    except Queue.Empty:
        # Deal with lack of data somehow
        result = None
    finally:
        proc.terminate()

    # Process data here, not in try block above, otherwise your process keeps running
    print result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_loop_with_timeout()
```

You could also accomplish this with a `Pipe`/`Connection` pair, but I'm not familiar with their API. Change the sleep time or `TIMEOUT` to check the behaviour for either case.

Comment: It works! :) But I how can I use it without the 'if main' statement? See my edit in the original question for my code.

Comment: @MistahX — you can call the `run_loop_with_timeout()` from anywhere you like. But if you're calling this script from the command line, you should always use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard, otherwise crazy things will happen if you ever try to import your script from another script.

Comment: @detly: Thanks for this answer. It inspired me in my trials to solve the problem of feeding stdin, capturing stdout, killing with watchdog timeouts in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575554/python-subprocess-with-timeout-and-large-output-64k/7753658#7753658)

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to kill a function after a certain amount of time without running the function in a separate process.  A better approach would probably be to rewrite the function so that it returns after a specified time:

```
import time

def big_loop(bob, timeout):
    x = bob
    start = time.time()
    end = start + timeout
    while time.time() < end:
        print time.time() - start
        # Do more stuff here as needed
```

Comment: yes how can I run it in a seperate process and then kill that process without killing the current script (still like to run code after the function call)  You can see my failed attempt...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just return from the loop?

```
start = time.time()
endt = start + 30
while True:
    now = time.time()
    if now > endt:
        return
    else:
        print end - start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,signal,time
cpid = os.fork()
if cpid == 0:
  while True:
     # do stuff
else:
  time.sleep(10)
  os.kill(cpid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

You can also check in the loop of a thread for an event, which is more portable and flexible as it allows other reactions than brute killing. However, this approach fails if `# do stuff` can take time (or even wait forever on some event).

Comment: Keep in mind that `os.fork` is only available on Unix-systems.

Comment: How can I do this in windows?

Comment: If I use a fork, does that reduce my memory?

Comment: @Cauder No, forking uses _additional_ memory. How much precisely depends on how much your process has allocated when forking, the operating system, and how much of the memory you change after forking.