# Why is this sending so many variables?

Tags: python

I have created a function `timeout_func` that will **run an another function normally** and return its output, but if the function exceeds 'secs' it will return a string 'failed'.
Basically, it's a workaround to timeout a function which could run infinitely. (python 2.7 on windows) (Why do I need a workaround, why can't I just make the function non-infinite? Because sometimes you just can't do that, it' called **bugs** in known processes ie: `fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)`

Anyways, my timeout_func was inspired from help I received here:
[kill a function after a certain time in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068361/kill-a-function-after-a-certain-time-in-windows)

The problem with my code is that for some reason the `do_this` function is receiving 14 variables instead of one. I get the error msg when running it by double clicking the script or from python.exe.    From IDLE you get no exception errors....
[image: exception error message]

However, if I change it to:

```
def do_this(bob, jim):
return bob, jim
```

It works just fine...

What's going on here? It doesn't like the 1 variable functions...?

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue


def wrapper(queue, func, func_args_tuple):
    result = func(*func_args_tuple)
    queue.put(result)
    queue.close()

def timeout_func(secs, func, func_args_tuple):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(1) # Maximum size is 1
    proc = multiprocessing.Process( target=wrapper, args=(queue, func, func_args_tuple) )
    proc.start()

    # Wait for TIMEOUT seconds
    try:
        result = queue.get(True, secs)
    except Queue.Empty:
        # Deal with lack of data somehow
        result = 'FAILED'
        print func_args_tuple
    finally:
        proc.terminate()

    return result


def do_this(bob):
    return bob

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print timeout_func( 10, do_this, ('i was returned') )
    x = raw_input('done')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`('i was returned')` is not a tuple. It evaluates to a string, just like `(3+2)` evaluated to an integer..

Calling `do_this(*('i was returned'))` passes each letter of the sequence `'i was returned'` as a separate argument - the equivalent of:

```
do_this('i', ' ', 'w', 'a', 's', ' ', 'r', 'e', 't', 'u', 'r', 'n', 'e', 'd')
```

---

Use `('i was returned',)` instead to force it to be a tuple (due to the trailing comma).