# Terminate model fitting with timeout

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, timeout, statsmodels

I am using a complicated model which potentially would takes a long computing time. I want to terminate the fitting process if it reached a given MAX_TIMEOUT time.

I saw some threads about this issue and found a few solutions.

1. using "threading" : I tried the following example but this did not work.
2. using "multiprocessing" : While this approach works successfully if it ran on the main thread(inside the if _*name_* == "main" block), it does not work under an interactive environment such as Jupyter Lab.
3. using "signal" : seems not feasible because I am using a Windows machine(Some methods only work on Unix systems)
4. using "timeout-decorator" : Due to some business restriction, I cannot use this library. Also this package uses "signal", hence it seems not work on Windows
5. using "wrapt_timeout_decorator" : This also not work if I ran script on Jupyter Lab. I suppose this is because of the same reason as "multiprocessing" which this library relies on.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

I am using Jupyter Lab on a Windows machine.

ref

- [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)
- [terminating a function call in python after n seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007496/terminating-a-function-call-in-python-after-n-seconds/28081214#28081214)

Code example

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

y = np.random.rand(5000)

# Complicated model
mod = sm.tsa.UnobservedComponents(
    y, 
    level = True, stochastic_level = True, 
    freq_seasonal = [{'period' : 200, 'harmonics' : 50}], stochastic_freq_seasonal = [True]
)


# Fitting the model(this will take more than 1 min)
fit = mod.fit()

def fit_with_timeout(mod, MAX_TIMEOUT) : 
    """
    Call mod.fit(). 
    If the computation succeeded within MAX_TIMEOUT, then return mod.fit(), otherwise this function should return None
    How I can solve this?
    """
```

The following is my threading approach that does not work. With this approach,

1. the target function will still be alive even after 'raise' triggered by terminate_alive_thread(t).
2. 'raise' will not be caught by the try-except block, which I want to do some work in the except block if the target function get timeout.

```
import threading
import time

# Some time-consuming function
def f(x) : 
    print(x, 'start')
    time.sleep(x)
    with open(str(x) + '.txt', 'w') as file : 
        file.write(str(x))
    return x

def terminate_alive_thread(t) : 
    if t.is_alive() : 
        raise 

# target function that will take 5 sec to finish
t_target = threading.Thread(target = f, args = (5, ))

# Set timer to terminate the target function 
timeout = 1
timer = threading.Timer(timeout, terminate_alive_thread, args = (t_target, ))

timer.start()
try : 
    t_target.start()
except : 
    print('Do some work in this block')
```

Comment: What are the issues with your approaches?

Comment: Of the above lists, I tried both threading and multiprocessing approaches but it does not work. I added my threading try to my original post.