# Do something when method exceed time

Tags: python, multithreading, time, python-multithreading

I'm curious whether is there some kind of time-out for methods so I can for example repeat the method after 50 seconds of acting like being idle.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/2071807) achieves this using [`signal.alarm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm), but I'm on Windows so this isn't available.

The only thing that comes to mind is to use `time.now()` and another thread, but it doesn't feel very effective.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/2071807) of any use?

Comment: @LondonRob I'm not sure because it is not working on Windows which I work on.

Comment: You could make the thread you want to wait on unconditionally acquire a lock when it starts execution and release it when it's finished. Then, in another or the main thread try to conditionally acquire the same lock repeatedly, doing other work or a `time.sleep()` between attempts. When that finally succeeds you know the other thread finished its execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [signal.alarm replacement in Windows \[Python\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644073/signal-alarm-replacement-in-windows-python)