# Print after specified time elapse of running in python code

Tags: python

I have a script where I want to put function, maybe `time()` to print for example "One hour of running" after some elapsed time while code is running.
For example
I start the script, after 1 hour maybe to print "Hour since running!" and after, every hour to display that. Is that even possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `signal`:

```
import signal

# Setup a signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, 
              lambda x,y: # You can put any function here
                 print("One hour since running!"))

# Request a signal 3600 secs later
signal.alarm(3600)

# Now, do your stuff

# 1 hr later:
# One hour since running!
```

Comment: It would be the great solution, but signal and alarm are not working on windows OS... :(

Comment: You didn't say you use Windows. Try this, then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644073/signal-alarm-replacement-in-windows-python

Comment: Helped a lot, thank you